# history.replaceState() not working, in script of <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am creating a addon.

The addon will be expanded in `<iframe>`.

```
<div>
  <iframe src="my/add-on/path">
    <!-- my contents is expanded -->
  </iframe>
</div>
```

The addon have `<input>` parameters (date and time) a button that get and display datas.

Our customer requires

- Browser's reload button must act as click the button.

To solve this, there is some problems.

- On reload, parent don't open my add-on because my add-on is inside `<iframe>` (parent can change  contents of `<iframe>`). But parent can detect what add-on to open by a URL parameter.

To solve this problem, I tried to use history.replaceState() but don't worked like this fiddle.
URL seems to be changed but not change URL inside browser bar.
https://jsfiddle.net/3ema2yg7/

I want to know the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using `parent.history.replaceState()` as

```
const url = new URL(parent.location.href)
url.searchParams.set('key', 'value')
parent.history.replaceState({}, '', url)
```

JSfiddle don't work this, warning `from accessing a cross-origin frame.`.
But my add-on work.

I am satisfied.